# Copying specific file extensions recursively using arrays with different extensions/arguments

Tags: bash, shell, unix, find

I have these lines of code

```
find . -name \*.sh -exec cp {} $1 \;
find . -name \*.py -exec cp {} $1 \;
find . -name \*.zsh -exec cp {} $1 \; 
find . -name \*.js -exec cp {} $1 \;
```

I want to put them all into a single codeline, by using extensions in an array. How could that be possibly achieved?

It should be something like:

```
find . ( -name *.sh -o *.py -o *.zsh -o *.js ) -exec cp {} $1 \;
```

Comment: unclear what you mean by `data type arrays'. (Please don't reply in comments, but update your Q with your best attempt at writing some "data type array" code). ..... While you may have reasonable reasons to need a one-liner, get things to work AND THEN worry about making a one liner. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find . \( -name '*.sh' -o -name '*.py' -o -name '*.zsh' -o -name '*.js' \) -exec cp {} "$1" \;
```

1. The parentheses need to be escaped as `\(` and `\)` to prevent the shell from interpreting them.
2. The `-name` predicate needs to be repeated for each extension.
3. The globs need to be quoted since we want `find` to interpret them, not the shell.
4. `$1` *should* be quoted in case in contains wildcards or spaces.

This can be made slightly more efficient by using `-exec +` rather than `-exec \;` to minimize the number of calls to `cp`.

```
find . \( -name '*.sh' -o -name '*.py' -o -name '*.zsh' -o -name '*.js' \) -exec cp -t "$1" {} +
```

If you want to store the extensions in an array, you'd need to build the predicate dynamically. You could do something like this, building a predicate array piece by piece:

```
extensions=(sh py zsh js)
predicate=(-false)
for e in "${extensions[@]}"; do predicate+=(-o -name "*.$e") done
find . \( "${predicate[@]}" \) -exec cp -t "$1" {} +
```

Comment: still get a bunch of error messages similar to this one 

    cp: will not overwrite just-created '/usr/local/bin/utils.py' with './_3rdP/powerlineShell/powerline-shell/powerline_shell/utils.py'

i am using the first option with, as the second one turned out not o work very well